# PouchDB on Hybrid Cordova App Not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, pouchdb, multi-device-hybrid-apps

Am new to Hybrid app development, Am using Cordova v5, Ionic and PouchDB for my app. It seems everything works fine on Ionic serve command, but any operation on PouchDB seems to be not working on actual devices running Android Lollipop.

Am explicitly specifying 'WebSQL' when creating pouchDB object. I don't know whether Am missing any steps.

Here is the code

```
 var houselst = JSON.parse('<some json string>');

new PouchDB('SH_HouseVisitDB', { adapter: 'websql' }).destroy().then(function () {
            return new PouchDB('SH_HouseVisitDB');
        }).then(function (db) {

      var doc = {
                    "_id": "houselist",
                    "items": houselst
                };

                //insert the doc to pouchDB
                db.put(doc);
                db.get('houselist').then(function (doc) {
                    vm.houselist = _.sortBy(doc.items, "name");
                    db.close();
                });
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you read the paragraph on the SQLite plugin in http://pouchdb.com/adapters.html ? What is the output of `db.info().then(function (info) { alert(info); });` ? And do you really need to use the plugin (see docs)?

Comment: Hello thriqon, Thank you for helping. When I run ionic serve command Am getting info object as follows   info: Object
auto_compaction: false
db_name: "SH_HouseVisitDB"
doc_count: 0
sqlite_plugin: false
update_seq: 0
websql_encoding: "UTF-8"
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the support.

Finally figured it out, We need to name the db with websql prefix. I found the solution from the following thread.

https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1207

Answer (score 0):

It's generally not advisable to try to use `new PouchDB(...)` as a promise for itself (e.g. `new PouchDB(...).then(...)`). That's an older style that we're moving away from because it causes issues in some Promise environments due to circular dependencies. Try doing `var db = new PouchDB(...);` and see if that helps!

Comment: Hello Nolan, I changed the code as you mentioned. Looks like Am missing some important step.    db.info shows sqlite_plugin : false :-(.

Comment: You can also try the IndexedDB adapter by just leaving out `adapter: 'websql'`. Also I wonder if there are any errors? You can see errors by attaching `.catch(console.log.bind(console))`. Also you don't need the sqlite_plugin on Lollipop in order for PouchDB to work; in fact, it works more consistently without it.